# Beaglebone AI - Pinmuxing vout-pins for PRU usage

Tags: device-tree, beagleboard

I am trying to configure a pinmux on the BBAI to use the UART from the PRU's. I am running Debian buster with 4.14.108-ti-r131 kernel.

This is part of my device tree overlay:

```
&cape_pins_default {
   pinctrl-single,pins = <
     DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD( 0x3614, PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE10 ) // P8.31a PRU1 TX
     DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD( 0x3610, PIN_INPUT  | MUX_MODE10 ) // P8.33a PRU1 RX
     DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD( 0x35E4, PIN_INPUT  | MUX_MODE10 ) // P8.43 PRU0 UART RX
     DRA7XX_CORE_IOPAD( 0x35E8, PIN_OUTPUT | MUX_MODE10 ) // P8.44 PRU0 UART TX
   >;
};
```

In BBBlack you need to disable HDMI or EMMC for some PRU pins, I tried it like so in `/boot/uEnv.txt`:

```
disable_uboot_overlay_video=1
disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
```

Is this also valid on the BBAI? The `show-pins` script after fiddling and rebooting for quite a while now still states `MUX_MODE0` and some `vout...` function (I assume this is some HDMI thing?)

```
P8.31a                   133   C8 0 slow         vout1_d14
P8.33a                   132   C6 0 slow         vout1_d1
P8.43                    121  F10 0 slow         vout1_d2
P8.44                    122  G11 0 slow         vout1_d3
```

Is there anything more I need to setup or that I missed?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out, that after reinstalling the BBAI image, that on the clean image, HDMI was disabled.
For making the device-tree overlay I used the [`am5729-beagleboneai.dts`](https://github.com/beagleboard/BeagleBoard-DeviceTrees/tree/v4.19.x-ti-overlays/src/arm)  and defined a custom `dtb=` in `/boot/uEnv.txt` as a base, which was the problem, because it enabled HDMI.

Extending the default overlay - which is `am572x-bone-common-univ.dtsi` - or by loading a pru overlay in the uEnv.txt file did the trick for me. There are plenty of examples for pru overlays for the BBAI in the beagleboards repo linked above, so I went with that.

```
uname_r=4.19.94-ti-r68
#dtb=

enable_uboot_overlays=1
uboot_overlay_pru=src/arm/overlays/BBAI-PR1_UART0.dtb
```

Comment: Hello...if you ever find to want to share, please do. I am a novice in PRU languages and would like to learn more.